# How to use existing sql server tables along with ASP.NET role and membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I have an application in Asp.net and using sql server to store user information.  There is a table named dbo.member which stores user information - fname, lastname, email, phone etc.  We use LDAP for authentication.

The entire application works on this member table.  There is a unique userid(not password) associated with each member.  I installed default aspnet_membership, aspnet_role tables by running aspnet_regsql.exe utility.

Now with increasing number of applications, handling members' information is becoming nightmare.  I hope Membership providers will solve this problem but I have doubts.

How can I integrate existing member table with default aspnet_membership table?  Or should I integrate since it is very limited?

Same is the case with aspnet_Profile - it is very limited and I have stored all profile information into member table.  We store more information and we want to query all that information for a user.

Should I create my own provider that will use dbo.Member table instead of dbo.Membership table and also with Profile provider?

I am new to membership providers so please suggest what would be appropriate to do in this case.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to leverage your existing tables then yes you will have to create custom providers. I know it sounds daunting but we implemented a complete custom membership solution and found it be to be fairly straight forward.

There is a video tutorial available on the asp.net website: http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider